# Mocha expect failing with Thor 0.19.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thor

After upgrading Thor from 0.18.1 to 0.19.1, I'm seeing a weird failure of Mocha (using test-unit)

```
/gems/2.1.0/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:395:
  in `output': unexpected invocation: #<IO:0x7fd6c986ab58>.puts() (Mocha::ExpectationError)

unsatisfied expectations:
  - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<IO:0x7fd6c986ab58>.puts('1.0.0')
from rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:389:in `nl'
```

Code:

```
def version
  say VERSION
end
```

Test:

```
def test_should_print_version
  $stdout.expects(:puts).with(VERSION)
  App::CLI.start %W(version)
end
```

Interestingly, `$stdout.expects(:print).with(VERSION + "\n")` works without issues. I'm using `ruby 2.1.1p76`

It seems that the first exception is due to `puts` being called and the second is due to it not being called. Should I be using `expect` in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the issue by redirecting $stdout to an instance of StringIO as suggested [here](http://goo.gl/eHtBnl)

```
require 'stringio'

module Kernel
  def capture_stdout
    out = StringIO.new
    $stdout = out
    yield
    return out
  ensure
    $stdout = STDOUT
  end
end
```

Updated test:

```
def test_should_print_version
  #$stdout.expects(:puts).with(VERSION)
  out = capture_stdout { App::CLI.start %W(version) }
  assert_match VERSION, out.string
end
```